# How do I pass a variable declared in HTML to a 3rd party event listener?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a Django application where I declare a variable at the bottom of the `<body>` tag, and I'm trying to use this variable inside of a 3rd part event listener function in my javascript code, but it keeps saying the variable is undefined.

I've tried passing the variable to the event listener using `.bind()` but that doesn't seem to work either. I've also tried getting the variable from `window.allJobsiteNames` but that was undefined also.

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/autoComplete.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/siren_search.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var allJobsiteNames = "{{ all_jobsite_names|safe }}".replace(/'/g, '"');
  </script>
</body>
```

```js
// siren_search.js

$(document).ready(function () {

  console.log(allJobsiteNames) // ==> prints correctly

  // Add an event listener to the searchbar
  document.querySelector("#searchbar").addEventListener("autoComplete", function (event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
  }.bind(allJobsiteNames));

  // User presses enter on the search bar
  $('#searchbar').on('keypress', function (event) {
    addSearchSpinner(event);
  });

});

// source code: https://github.com/TarekRaafat/autoComplete.js
new autoComplete({
  data: {                              
    src: allJobsiteNames, // allJobsiteNames is not defined
  },

  // some code
});
```

The exact error I get is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: allJobsiteNames is not defined
>       at siren_search.js:261 (anonymous) @ siren_search.js:261

Comment: Are you sure that js is present in the rendered html? It's not being overwritten by template inheritance?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure that I full understand the question, but when I `console.log(allJobsiteNames)` in both the HTML page and the javascript file it outputs the correct result. However the variable isn't being defined in the `autoComplete` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order your JavaScript is executed.

At the time your siren_search.js is executed, the `allJobsiteNames` is not defined yet.

Change the order of your scripts

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var allJobsiteNames = "{{ all_jobsite_names|safe }}".replace(/'/g, '"');
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/autoComplete.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/siren_search.js' %}"></script>
</body>
```

The `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` part waits the page to finish loading thus is executed asynchronous after the definition of the `allJobsiteNames`.

Comment: Wow i'm an idiot, i'm pretty sure this fixed it. I have a new error now (such is life), but it's definitely reading in the variable correctly. Thank you!